# Defragging a mac with Drive Genius 3

Tags: macos, defragment

I've heard many times over that OSX's system for handling files does away with the need to defragment my HDD unlike in Windows. However, I tried out Drive Genius 3 and it shows that 75% of my HDD that's less than a year old is fragmented. Apple genius bars supposedly use Drive Genius in their yearly Applecare tuneups..

Who should I believe?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this as well. Apple's site says defragmentation is not necessary (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1375) but I don't see how that's possible. A contiguous file will be read more quickly than a fragmented file in any situation, as far as I know.

Comment: Apple and friends say that the filesystem apple uses (HFS+) is very good at not leaving fragmenting files, so they wouldn't need defragmenting in the first place.

Comment: @James This post maybe helpful http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/829/do-macs-need-to-be-defragmented

Comment: @James Possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/17428/do-i-need-to-defragment-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

When a file is opened on an HFS+ volume, the following conditions are tested:

- The file is less than 20 MB in size
- The file is not already busy
- The file is not read only
- The file is fragmented (the eighth extent descriptor in its extend
  record has a non-zero block count)
- The system uptime is at least 3 minutes

If all the above are satisfied, the file is relocated (de-fragmented) on-the-fly.

---

Source: Bonus contents of "*What is Mac OS X?*", Amit Singh (© 1994-2010)

---

So you should act in order to prevent files from fragmenting too much (partitions/compression/etc) and, if needed, defragment with one of those third-party tools.